# Map.get() optimization in ?: ternary operator

Tags: java, optimization, dictionary, compiler-optimization

Consider the following code:

```
java.util.Map<String, String> map = new java.util.HashMap<String, String>();
...
String key = "A";
String value = map.get(key) == null? "DEFAULT_VALUE" : map.get(key); // (1)
```

Would **the compiler** optimize the line `(1)` something similar to:

```
String tmp = map.get(key);
String value = tmp == null? "DEFAULT_VALUE" : tmp;
```

(or to:

```
String value = map.get(key);
if(value == null) value = "DEFAULT_VALUE";
```

)
?

Comment: I'd personally do the latter. There isn't that much difference in it, but it's generally better to err on the side of readability which I think the latter wins. (You would also not believe the number of people I've come across that don't know what the ternary operator does, so it's generally best avoided unless it's very clear).

Comment: In order to perform that optimization, the optimizer would have to know that `map.get(key)` returns the same value every time it's called (without any intervening changes to `map` or `key`).

Comment: The compiler does near to none optimizations, the JIT does. Besides, I would always favor clarity over micro optimizations.

Comment: keep in mind that `get(key)==null` is different than `!containsKey(key)` and the JIT wont optimize it

Comment: @Gabe I think it was just a misplaced label and the question is about how to optimise it manually. (And make it a bit more thread-safe too, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: @biziclop, the question was edited to say the compiler

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if you are asking which corresponds to what the compiler will make of the original expression, in which case the answer is:

Neither--

In the example you are calling map.get() twice; the compiler can't know that there are no side effects, so it will call it twice when a value is found.

Probably closest to

```
String tmp = map.get(key);
String value;
if (tmp == null)
    value= "DEFAULT_VALUE";
else
    value = map.get(key);
```

Or if you are asking which alternative is most efficient, in which case the answer is:

The second alternative is probably slightly better because it does not require an additional local variable.  An additional local variable imposes a slight overhead on the JVM, but it will probably amount to nothing at runtime once the JIT gets through with it.

Comment: He's asking for an optimisation, not something exactly equivalent. There's no need to do duplicate the undesirable second call to get the value.

Comment: Guys, I forgot the keyword `compiler` in my question, so this post answers my question (another answers don't). Thanks.

Comment: Considering that the `get()` code is pretty short I absolutely wouldn't put it behind -c2 to inline the get call. And then it doesn't look tpp hard to show that there are no side effects. Depends basically on the inline budget of the method. Although if the question really means "the compiler" ala javac you're obviously right - but why should anyone care?

Answer (score 3):

Your second option which is :

```
String value = map.get(key);
if(value == null) {
    value = "DEFAULT_VALUE";
}
```

is better from first one reason:

1. You dont create an extra reference "tmp"
2. You dont execute else which you do as part of your ternary comparison.

Comment: the question is asking about `compiler` optimization, and it was clearly specified after 10 minutes after the question asked. so why down votes?

Comment: @Kowser That would be why. See my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `IF` one is preferable.

Its more readable & self explained.

Additionally: execution time is not a big deal, at least here.

Comment: The question isn't which is 'better', the question is whether the compiler carries out the 'optimization' mentioned. The answer is that it can't.

Comment: @EJP: yes agreed, I misunderstood the question first time.

Comment: @EJP: I just reviewed the question. Again to clarify, the question was modified after few answer were posted and deviated from the question initially asked (as I understood)!. Check the revision again, please.